# How can i pass data between many angular 9 projects without using localStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular9

I have two angular projects Parent, Library and two others
and i want to pass data when something changes in library to subscribe in parent project
when i press button in library, i want this event click to send boolean variable to parent project

I tried to use RabbitMQ Protocol but it doesn't work
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you tried to use EventEmitter or is there any reason you can't use it?

Comment: I am not in the same project to use EventEmitter

Comment: Isn't it library <=> project communication? Could you please give us more details?

Comment: i have library project and 3 other one of them is the root project parent..... i want when i press button save in the library project.. the parent refresh

Comment: Do you implement the library project to the parent one?

Comment: No i don't, the parent one is unrelated to the library

Comment: You can have a look at ModuleFederation, but it will require you to have a monorepo structure